# when i am performing migration from sql server to mysql the below error is coming in workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench, database-migration

when i am performing migration from sql server to mysql the below error is coming in workbench.

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connecting to Mssql@DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS...
Opening ODBC connection to DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE={};UID=sa;PWD=XXXX;...
ERROR: Connection failed: No open connection to Mssql@DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\db_mssql_grt.py", line 124, in connect
    con = db_driver.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\workbench\db_driver.py", line 91, in connect
    connection = library.connect(connection_string, password=password)
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')
Connecting to Mssql@DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS...
Opening ODBC connection to DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE={};UID=sa;PWD=XXXX;...
ERROR: Connection failed: No open connection to Mssql@DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IPAddress\SQLEXPRESS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\db_mssql_grt.py", line 124, in connect
    con = db_driver.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\workbench\db_driver.py", line 91, in connect
    connection = library.connect(connection_string, password=password)
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 66, in run
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 443, in task_connect
    raise e
SystemError: Error("('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.connect
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: Error("('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect);
 [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.connect
ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': SystemError('Error("(\'08001\', \'[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)\')"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.connect',)

Failed
```

so any one can help me to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

You will need to try some diagnose from your site with a text editor.

1 ) Open the
**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\db_mssql_grt.py** file with a notepad or notepad++ and around **line 174** you'll find a line that looks like:

```
 ver_string = execute_query(connection, "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')").fetchone()[0]
```

2) Change that to:

```
ver_string = execute_query(connection, "SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)").fetchone()[0]
```

Then save and retry. Thanks!

Reference : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66030